# Hiding/Unhiding a slide in Keynote for iPadOS

Tags: ios, keynote, ipados

How can one hide/unhide slide(s) in Keynote for iPadOS?

I find my self very often having to edit keynote presentations (stored in iCloud) while I have no access to my MacBook and I can say that working on iPad is pretty nice and all, but I cannot figure this one thing out.

Has anyone ever come across this and has a way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean skipping a slide during a presentation, i.e., the slide will be present, but will not be shown during the presentation. Here is how to do it in Keynote for iPadOS/iOS:

1. **In the slide navigator**: Tap the slide to select it, tap it again, then tap **Skip Slide** (or **Unskip Slide** to include it back again). You might need to tap ▶️, or rotate your device to see the Skip Slide/Unskip Slide command.
2. **In the light table view**: Tap to select a slide or select multiple slides, then tap the [image: Skip button] (the Skip button) or [image: Unskip button] (the Unskip button) at the bottom of the screen.

<sub>The directions have been taken from the Apple Support pages for [iOS](https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote-iphone/skip-or-unskip-a-slide-tan9cbb7c9fe/ios) and [iPadOS](https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote-ipad/skip-or-unskip-a-slide-tan9cbb7c9fe/ipados)</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ok, so it was a bad translation issue in my system language - Greek. While "hide slide" is correctly translated, the "unskilled" option is displayed as "undo"